# Android Jobservice being destroyed

Tags: android, job-scheduling

I put up a Jobservice to do some things. For test purpose I let it run every thirty seconds. To find the problem I reduced the service down to do nothing(!).
I know, that a job can be stopped by the system; if the onStopJob method returns true it will be restarted. This happens and works well, although I am wondering, how often and at which time (in the middle of the night, while the phone is just laying on the table!).
To check all these, I am using SharedPreferences, keeping track of stops and restarts.
I found out however, that the job is not only stopped, but sometimes completely being destroyed.
I then put up a restart routine in the OnDestroy method. This does not work. The job is being restarted, but immediately being destroyed again.
So I have some questions:
Why is it destroyed in the first place?
And why isnt it possible to restart it?
And what can I do to make it more stable?
Tried on a Galaxy S4 under Android 5.0.1 and XPeria Z2 under 6.0
Compiled against MinSDK 5.0, TargetSDK 6.0.
Here is the code of my JobSchedulerService:

```
public class  JobSchedulerService extends JobService implements
    DataApi.DataListener,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener 
{

private boolean stoppedByUser = false;
public DateFormat formatter;
String stoptimeText;
public GregorianCalendar apptTime;
public Context myCnt;

@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params){
        doJob(this);
        jobFinished(params, false );
    return true;
}

public void doJob(Context context){
    myCnt = context;
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(myCnt);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    stoptimeText = prefs.getString("stopped","not yet stopped");
    editor.putString("started", "Job was running at " + timeNow());
    editor.apply();
    // do something here
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    stoppedByUser = prefs.getBoolean("stoppedByUser", false);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    stoptimeText += "Job stopped autom. at " + timeNow();
    editor.putString("stopped", stoptimeText);
    editor.apply();
    if (stoppedByUser){
        stoppedByUser = false;
        editor.putBoolean("stoppedByUser", false);
        stoptimeText += "OnStopJob called by user-stop at " + timeNow();
        editor.putString("stopped", stoptimeText);
        editor.apply();
        return false;
    }
    else return true;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    stoppedByUser = prefs.getBoolean("stoppedByUser", false);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    stoptimeText += "Job was destroyed at "+ timeNow();
    editor.putString("stopped", stoptimeText);
    editor.apply();
    if (!stoppedByUser){
        JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(1,
                new ComponentName(getPackageName(), JobSchedulerService.class.getName()));
        builder.setPeriodic(30 * 1000);
        builder.setPersisted(true);
        stoptimeText += "Job rest. after dstr. at " + timeNow();
        editor.putString("stopped", stoptimeText);
        editor.putString("started", "Auto update started after destroy! Check if really running!");
        editor.apply();
    }
    else {
        stoptimeText += "OnDestroy called by user-stop at " + timeNow();
        editor.putString("stopped", stoptimeText);
        editor.apply();
    }
}

public String timeNow(){
    apptTime = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd./HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    return formatter.format(apptTime.getTimeInMillis());
}

@Override
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
}
}
```

And here is my MainActivity (shortened):

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myCnt = this;

    initGoogleApiClient();

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    if (tabLayout != null)
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    mJobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

//.......

public void startJob(){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("started", "auto updates started by user!");
    editor.putBoolean("stoppedByUser", false);
    editor.apply();

    JobSchedulerService jss = new JobSchedulerService(); // used to "first run" the job, so there is no waiting time for the user
    jss.doJob(myCnt);

    JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(1,
            new ComponentName(getPackageName(), JobSchedulerService.class.getName()));
    builder.setPeriodic(30 * 1000);
    builder.setPersisted(true);

    if (mJobScheduler.schedule(builder.build()) <= 0) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failure starting Jobservice!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After long research I found the following to be the problem:
In my

```
// do something here
```

I had an Async Task. However, according to Google, this is only working in the UI Thread (see: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).
Having this in my JobSchedulerService caused it to be destroyed after some time.
I am now using a (regular) separate thread to "do something" in the Service, and it works.